# jQuery application - Close menu after clicking on an anchor link

Tags: jquery

I found a wonderful full-screen menu for our homepages, kindly provided by Maxime Beguin.

There are two problems I would like to solve to make it work perfectly.

1. one of the often asked problems that the menu should close when you press on the anchor link!
2. it seems to scroll on the page, although the author has written overflow:hidden added?

Here is the jQuery coder:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circular-revealer@0.0.8/dist/index.iife.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>

  
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    
    // Variables
    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dacm__section .dacm__menu-row-content .et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu > li > a');
    const actionBtn = document.querySelector('.hamburger-init');
    const rowContent = document.querySelector('.dacm__menu-row-content');
    const body = document.body;
    
    // Avoid FOUC
    rowContent.classList.remove('no-fouc');
    
    // Add delay to each menu links
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++){
      $(menuItems[i]).css('--order', i);
    };
    
    // Insert the menu content inside the hamburger menu
    $('.dacm__menu-row-content').insertAfter('.dacm__menu-row .hamburger'); 

    // Ciruclar Reveal Init
    const revealerNav = window.revealer({
      revealElementSelector: '.dacm__menu-row-content',
      options: {
        anchorSelector: '.hamburger-init',
      },
    });

    // Hamburger Animation + reveal effect
    actionBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!revealerNav.isRevealed()) {
        revealerNav.reveal();
        actionBtn.setAttribute('data-open', true);
        rowContent.setAttribute('data-open', true);
        rowContent.classList.add('visible');
        body.classList.add('dacm__menu--open');
      } else {
        actionBtn.setAttribute('data-open', false);
        rowContent.setAttribute('data-open', false);
        setTimeout(function(){
          revealerNav.hide();
          rowContent.classList.remove('visible');
          body.classList.remove('dacm__menu--open');
        }, (menuItems.length * 100) + 300)
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.